# Convert SQL Date Time formatting (MySQL to SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Being a newbie at SQL - I am trailling a Data Factory in Azure, and all is running but I am not getting any results in the destination table.

I have found the issue is likely to be a mismatch in date formatting that i have set in the lookup date table [dbo].[watermarktable]

The source table is coming from Maria/MySQL ODBC driver with a column named [NewWatermarkValue] to the left of the image.

I have created a stored procedure on the right, which sets a date time.

Could anyone please suggest the formatting I need in the [WatermarkValue] statement?

[image: MSQL vs SQL with statement]

Comment: Have you looked the converting funktions STR_TO_DATE (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) an DATE_FORMAT (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: In your example the dates are the same, but the times are different. Could a possible solution be to take only the date part e.g. `DATE(NewWatermarkValue) = DATE(WatermarkValue)`?